# How to make curl request hit server at exactly 12:00:00:000

Tags: curl, time, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I want to send a curl request that reaches the server exactly between 12:00:00:000 and 12:00:00:070 milliseconds.

I tried sending requests from 11:58:00 to 11:59:59 and measuring the TTFB (Time To First Byte).  Then running a linear regression on the TTFB array (I used milliseconds since Unix epoch as X-axis).

And then predicting when a request, if sent now, would hit the server and I would send it as soon as the prediction said so.

But I have a lot of errors using this method. I'm off by 200 milliseconds on average each time, It just looks quite random. Here's my log:

TTFB : 429.696  ERROR: 14.833935636827

TTFB : 402.189  ERROR: 42.721613882814

TTFB : 708.965  ERROR: -263.71603087697

TTFB : 885.601  ERROR: -439.85133800703

TTFB : 576.66  ERROR: -130.14028522262

TTFB : 3959.547  ERROR: -3512.2112723293

TTFB : 1804.399  ERROR: -1353.7299144077

TTFB : 1499.568  ERROR: -1044.7412000829

TTFB : 884.19  ERROR: -424.52168290527

TTFB : 577.796  ERROR: -113.20088165977

TTFB : 577.608  ERROR: -108.24005577003

Error is: prediction - actual TTFB

Does anyone a suggestions how I could achieve something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
forgot to mention this, It's a server with a lot of traffic coming in at exactly 12:00 every day, so I figured the traffic would be rising every second and TTFB would go up, that's why I'm using linear regression. I'm not sure if that's the best tool to use here though.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a linear regression. A simple `mean` over the time difference between sending and receiving should be enough

Comment: @drops sorry forgot to mention this, It's a server with a lot of traffic coming in at exactly 12:00 every day, so I figured the traffic would be rising every second and TTFB would go up as a result

Comment: Are you trying to snipe auctions? This smells like automating something that isn't meant to be automated ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer yeah its a giveaway, it's not against the rules so I figured I'd try